# Different imageview size in cardview on different image screens

Tags: android, imageview, android-cardview

I am using imageview in cardview with recycler. I also created folders for different screen sizes as well. It works fine for small screen phones and tablets
but there is a scaling issue with phone screen more than 5.5 inches[image: Screenshot on phone having screen size 5.5 (420dp)]

[image: Screenshot on phone having screen size (600dp)]

Code is as follows:

cardview.xml (420dp)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:id="@+id/card_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
         android:elevation="3dp"
         card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ritu"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>


            </RelativeLayout>

          </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

       </LinearLayout>
```

cardview.xml (600dp)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:id="@+id/card_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
         android:elevation="3dp"
         card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ritu"/>
        <!---->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>


            </RelativeLayout>

          </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

       </LinearLayout>
```

So in the second screenshot, you can see image  scaleType = fitXY is not working. Its working with all different screens including tablets as well using the same code

Comment: YOu should design for different screens

Comment: I designed but not getting exact screen size. As you can check the code it's for 2 screens. I've designed  4 different screens Default,360dp,420dp,560dp,720dp.

Answer (score 6):

Each Drawable is stored as individual files in one of the **`res/drawable`** folders. You should store images for different resolutions in the **`-mdpi, -hdpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi`** subfolders of **`res/drawable`**.

You should place each type of resource in a specific **subdirectory** of your **`project's res/ directory`**. Make sure, you did this properly or not.

You can add below in your manifest section

```
<supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Read [**`Support different screen sizes`**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

Comment: Thanx for help. I'm downloading all images from the server, then how can I put them in drawable folder. Please assist me further.

Comment: @PranshuK It will be better if you use Constrantlayout. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: @PranshuK `I'm downloading all images from the server, then how can I put them in drawable folder` if your images come from server end then dont store it.

Comment: @PranshuK add below property in imageview `android:adjustViewBounds="true"android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: fyi, a comment thread that you (and I) are involved in is being discussed in the meta site: [Can we stop the rude 'Pal' and 'Bro' comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375313/522444)

Answer (score 2):

1) Add 
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
inside of image view tag.

2) Make relative layout l, width and height to wrap content.

3) (Optional) Make scale type to centercrop.

Comment: Appreciate your help! But it didn't work on cardview.xml (600dp) Should I change the screen size?

Comment: adjustViewbounds helps you to get the correct image resolution on any devices, even if you won't create separate drawable folders for each. If you already got the expected result, you can skip this. Thank you.